# Is there a native function in Matlab that export string array to csv and vice versa?

Tags: matlab, export-to-csv

Now that [string array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) is a thing since R2016b, is there a native function that export a string array to csv file and vice versa?

A function that fills the same role of `csvread` and `csvwrite` for numeric arrays in the old days but for string arrays. And to relax the requirement, say the string array contains columns of pure strings and columns of pure doubles. Stock prices with time stamp strings would be an example.

Native = not looping with `fprintf`. But if you are certain Matlab hasn't included any such functions yet, feel free to answer with the best approach thusfar without any restrictions.

---

Without any native function, pre-R2013a, looping with `fprintf` is the only way I can think of. And it was awful. Given past reputation of inefficiency, I still don't trust looping in Matlab.

Post-R2016b, one can convert a string array to cell array with `num2cell` and then to table with `cell2table`. Table can be written to csv file with `writetable`. This is actually fast, as `writetable` is fast. Only `num2cell` slows down the whole process a little. However, formatting is impossible along the way.

Post-R2019a, `cell2table` can be skipped with `writecell`, which is nice but the time consuming (slightly) step is `num2cell` and formatting should still be impossible. (I don't have R2019a to test it.)

Is there a better way or is it another one of those basic things left to be desired about Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`writematix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writematrix.html) and [`readmatrix`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readmatrix.html) are the functions to do that since R2019a.

```
%If S1 is a string array that you want to `foobar.csv` then:
writematrix(S1,'foobar.csv');

%To read this csv file back into MATLAB as the same string array, use:
S2 = readmatrix('foobar.csv','OutputType','string');

%Verifying the result:
isequal(S1,S2)
```

```
ans =
  logical
   1
```

---

Loops have been significantly improved since R2015b. Not all loops are slow and not all vectorised versions are faster. The correct approach is to [timeit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any pre-R2019a methods?

Comment: Pre-R2019a methods are already mentioned by you. Any other variant of those will be more or less similar